# Check total space used in azure storage accounts in my subscription

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-billing-api

Because I have been charge a lot of money by storage, and I have so many storage account. I want to know how can I check how much my total storage usage in my subscription ?

I have check this [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629557/check-space-used-in-azure-storage-accounts-in-my-subscription), but they only provide how to check each storage account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way:

Nav to azure portal -> Monitor -> Storage accounts: Then select your subscription; For storage accounts, select "All" -> At last, click "Capacity". The screenshot as below:

[image]

Remember that you should calculate the **total space used** one by one, there is no such built-in feature. Or you can write a code calculate **total space used** one by one.