# Query Azure Storage Account Used Capacity - PowerShell Script?

Tags: azure, powershell

I was wondering is there a reliable PowerShell script that gets Used Capacity for a storage account in Azure? Current script we are using is inconsistent- sometimes it returns results and sometimes it is blank values.

The script here works fine, just sometimes returns blank values for some accounts, or all.

```
Script:
#CAPACITY
$SAID = $storageAccount.Id
$usedCapacity = (Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $SAID -MetricName "UsedCapacity").Data
$usedCapacityInMB = $usedCapacity.Average/1024/1024
```

Many thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is correct (and you can find examples of [other Stack Overflow users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59648571/9599292) using it as well), but unfortunately, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29070).  Although it doesn't help from a scripting standpoint, it should be noted that this doesn't seem to affect the portal.

**Reference:**

- GitHub Known Issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29070#issuecomment-485531645
- Report 1: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd21e2cb-622f-4eb7-a068-9c140edd6e87/getazmetric-sporadically-refuses-to-return-results?forum=windowsazuredata
- Report 2: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/37300102-get-azmetrics-for-storage-accounts-returns-null-ca